# How do I enable debugging af a XCUITest target in XCode 8.3?

Tags: debugging, xctest, uitest, xcode8

I'm running a UI test in Xcode but the debugger don't stop at any break point in the test code nor in the application code.
It seems like there is no debugging enabled for my test target.

According to Apples doc I should be able to debug my test code, but execution dosent stop at a regular breakpoint.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/06-debugging_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH6-SW1

In my schema I have checked the debug flag in the Test-action.
[image: Schema configuration]

The breakpoint is in the test code. Setting a breakpoint in my unit test code succesfully stops the execusion.

Adding a ui test target to a new project, debugging works fine.
But adding a ui test target to my project don't work.

I'm running out of ideas, anyone that have experienced this too?

Comment: Where is your breakpoint?

Comment: The breakpoint is in the uitest code. I cant debug anything while hitting "Test". Doing the same thing on a unit test target and the execution stops as expected in the unit test code.

Comment: Debugging works fine when I'm adding a ui test target to a new clean project. So it must be a mis-configuration somewhere in my project. But not affecting the unit test target.